# how can i Use this Javascript twice in a same page

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone help me in this, i dont know JS at all , i want to use this twice in one page.

can someone give me the correct codings to it

```
<div id="myTypingText"></div>
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript" > 
{
    var myString = "Here is my text.";
    var myArray = myString.split("");
    var loopTimer;
    function frameLooper() {
        if (myArray.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML += myArray.shift();
        } else {
            clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        }
        loopTimer = setTimeout('frameLooper()', 70);
    }
    frameLooper();
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Put it in a function and call this function twice.

Comment: You really need to read some books before posting on stack overflow, this is Javascript 101

Comment: Why is the content of your script tag within `{}`?

Comment: I assume what you are trying to do is object oriented javascript. Here's a good starter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: Also, you probably shouldn't ask someone to write your code for you on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function fun(){
        var myString = "Here is my text.";
        var myArray = myString.split("");
        var loopTimer;
        function frameLooper() {
           if(myArray.length > 0) {
              document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML += myArray.shift();
           } else {
             clearTimeout(loopTimer); 
           }
           loopTimer = setTimeout('frameLooper()',70);
        }
        frameLooper();
   }

fun()// first call
fun()// second call
```

Comment: What you want from this?

Comment: I want to have "here is my text" in top and bottom of my page

Comment: You have to use different id for top and bottom element. pass id in fun and use it for top and bottom .